# url ajax lookup

Tags: php, ajax, url

no clue what im looking for, so if you can tell me what this is, what i should lookup for this.

```
http://website.com/page.php#article23
```

The Number sign isnt a url request, like GET or POST, its more of a "Ahref Name", but this was with ajax, where it would change the whole frame, wondering what its called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the # seperates the URI from the fragment identifier. See [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)